# UI on windows CE 5.0

Tags: windows-ce

I am a windows phone developer. I recently started working on windows CE. I noticed all I have for the UI is a toolbox with a few controls and drag and drop. As a mobile developer I am used to a design language XAML and a backend logic language c#. My question how do i design an application on windows CE. does it has any language (like XAML for windows Phone). and why can't I find a code editor for the UI in visual studio 2008 developing for windows CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see many people use Qt. You can easily create UIs like the one on smartphones or even complex 3D ones. Also Qt is cross platform, so if you decide to change the OS you should be able to take your UI with you.

XAML is possible, but is also works with C++ and not with C#.
You will use Blend for creating the UI.
Here some info to get you started:
http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-create-a-silverlight-application

Some other UI frameworks for WinCE:
http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/gui

Comment: It states that Qt too uses c++ for backend programming. So I could use XAML or Qt for designing but I'll have to use visual c++ for the backend logic. right?